# ProtectedSessionStorage not working when deploying to iis

Tags: blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using ProtectedSessionStorage to persists data between circuit resets.
I can set and read the data while debugging on my machine. However when deploying to IIS on windows 10 as soon as the code try to read or write to the session storage I get the following error message:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {85abab8d-73f8-4c61-a935-55e832f56a69} was not found in the key ring.

I have the following code to my service configuration

```
services.AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\tmp-keys"))
                .ProtectKeysWithDpapi();
```

changed the application pool to NetworkService still the same issue.
any idea on how to solve this.

Comment: How about change the pool to Administrator

Comment: I tried changing the pool to use my account which have administrator privilege's, still having the same problem.

Comment: I recommand using process monitor to check "access deny" events. It should be something related to key access permission.